# tinyMCE 'SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'duplicate''?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, text-editor

I got `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'duplicate'` error and I replaced the old tinyMCE with new version 3.5.5

Still I am getting the same error on click of a button.

Is it problem with `prototype/scriptaculous` used? DO I need to upgrade them as well?